# How can I use a window object in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli, window-object

I tried to put the following code to get a window object in angular 2:

```js
      @Component({
          selector: 'app-slider',
          templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
          providers: [
            SliderService, 
            { provide: "windowObject", useValue: window}
          ]
        })
        export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
        
          sliderList: Slider[] = [];
        
          constructor( private _sliderservice:SliderService, @Inject("windowObject") private _window:window ) { }
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be considered a duplicate. 1) The other question is specifically about an angular service, whereas this is more broad (to include e.g., angular components). 2) The other question is specifically about how to inject, whereas there may be occasions when injection is not needed. If either of these two points is true, this is not a duplicate, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a provider for that. `window` is a global object and is accessible directly in your class

Comment: Using window from the global JS object will make your Angular app brittle and will not work if you ever want to do server side rendering.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy honest question: would it still be brittle if you use the 'optional chaining' question mark? E.g., ```window?.navigator```

Comment: @Marcus no, that would guard against `window` being null. Or you could wrap code that uses `window` in an `if (window) {...}` guard.

Comment: Except when it's undefined, yes, it's a global object

Comment: Check this article: https://medium.com/@abampakos/a-better-angular-window-b20da0e02dd7